# Intuition on the Dirichlet energy on a manifold in local coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, intuition

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and consider the dirichlet energy of a function $f$
given by

\begin{equation} \int_M g(\operatorname{grad} f, \operatorname{grad} f)\ d \mu \end{equation}

where $d\mu$ is the standard volume form.

In local coordinates, the gradient can be written as

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{grad} f = \sum_{i,j} g^{ij} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}f) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} .
\end{equation}

Thus locally we have

\begin{equation}
g(\operatorname{grad} f, \operatorname{grad} f) = (\partial f)^T g^{-1}  (\partial f).
\end{equation}

(This might be also seen by observing $df = \sum_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}f$ dx^j and then using the dual-norm relation of $\operatorname{grad} f)$ and $df$).

The volume form in local coordinates is $$ d\mu =  \sqrt{\det g} dx^1 \land ... dx^n .$$

Thus locally in some neighborhood $W$ we can write

\begin{equation} \int_W g(\operatorname{grad} f, \operatorname{grad} f)\ d \mu =  \int_U (\partial f)^T g^{-1}  (\partial f)  \sqrt{\det g} dx^1 \land ... dx^n = \int_{gU}   (\partial f)^T g^{-2}  (\partial f) dx^1 \land ... dx^n\end{equation}
where the last line is just applying the transformation rule.

I'm now looking for some intuitive explanation of the last equation. I can see that the formulas work, but I can not intuitively understand why we shold some vector and push it through the scalar product that is given by the second power of the inverse of our metric and that this then somehow is the natural extension of dirichlet energy.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `Why is this an extension of the Dirichlet energy?`: simply because it is given by $\int_M \|\nabla f\|^2$!

Comment: "...where the last line is just applying the transformation rule.": I do not see how you get the last equality. And what does $gU$ mean?

Comment: @Deane you are right it seems like I was just assuming $g$ to be constant! (and $gU$ should be $g^{-\frac{1}{2}} U$.

Comment: OK. When you're trying to figure something out, it's extremely useful to identify clearly what type each variable represents: scalar constant, function, tangent vector, tangent vector field, cotangent vector, $1$-form, symmetric $2$-tensor etc. It helps you detect errors or misunderstandings in your formulas and calculations.